# At runtime, how can I limit the number of java threads

Tags: java, multithreading, runtime

I am running a genome assembly program *Trinity, http://trinityrnaseq.sourceforge.net/, if interested) on one of the XSEDE resources. The hardware limits the number of threads to 2500, which the program always wants to exceed... It there an easy way to limit the number of threads executed? I have tried `-XX:ParallelGCThreads=16`, but this seems to introduce new errors.

So, is there a runtime command to limit the total number of threads??

Comment: The trouble is, even if you could tell the JVM to limit the number of threads, the Trinity application logic would still try to obtain more threads and thus would fail (or block) at runtime.  It seems like you really want to patch the Trinity codebase to use a different forking/thread creation strategy, and that would take getting their source and changing it.

Comment: I skimmed the Trinity docs and saw a --CPU option.  Have you tried that?

Comment: I skimmed the Trinity docs and saw a --CPU option.  Have you tried that?

Comment: yeah, that is used for some of the steps, but the java steps are run in a different way (that I am not totally understanding). Anyway, all the runs are set --CPU 8

Comment: The problem with placing a limit is that when the limit is reached what do you want it to do. e.g. by default you will get an OutOfMemoryError. You are better off not trying to create too many threads.  How many cpus do you have? Do you need more than this number of threads?

Comment: I am just wondering if there is a tradeoff between the number of threads and execution time (thinking posix threading).  The specifics of the system, Blacklight (http://www.psc.edu/machines/sgi/uv/blacklight.php) are in brief, 4096 cores, floating point capacity 37 Tflops, 16Tb RAM in shared mem config..

Answer (score 2):

Use an Executor or ExecutorService.  Does what bragboy suggests but it's built in to Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom queue that runs as a separate process that handles the number of threads limitation. The advantage of this is that you can opt to either limit the threads or you can still keep adding the number of threads. You will probably have a `addToQueue(Thread t)` class and subsequently a consumer consuming all these threads. The Queue will know how many threads are actively running. The daemon process will fire the `consume()` method of this queue at will if the threads are well within the range. And after every thread finishes or compeltes it job, it reports back to the queue. The Queue that you maintain can be a priority queue if you feel there should be a priority on the running tasks. This not only removes the dependency on the JVM but also makes your program look cleaner.